# How i can set a selection for a row on a pagination page with datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

i trie do add a selection of a row for my datatables

For the first page of pagination this code works

```
$( '#dt_row_id_'+myid ).addClass('selected');
```

If the selected row is not on first page of the pagination, it wont work.

**How can i add the selection for a row on the other result pages?**

Datatable Example

```
    <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>Office</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>Start date</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                   <th><a href="#" id="selectall">Select all</a></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
           
            <tbody>
                <tr id="dt_row_id_1">
                    <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                    <td>System Architect</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>61</td>
                    <td>2011/04/25</td>
                    <td>$320,800</td>
                     <td> <input type="checkbox" class="record"></td>
                </tr>
<tr id="dt_row_id_2">
                    <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                    <td>System Architect</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>61</td>
                    <td>2011/04/25</td>
                    <td>$320,800</td>
                     <td> <input type="checkbox" class="record"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="dt_row_id_3">
                    <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                    <td>System Architect</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>61</td>
                    <td>2011/04/25</td>
                    <td>$320,800</td>
                     <td> <input type="checkbox" class="record"></td>
                </tr>
...
```

Comment: where do you add class? is it on click event ?

Comment: @Pirate I  add the class on pageload, so on pageload the first page of the datatable is open

Comment: @relo80 Are you using client-side processing mode or server-side processing mode, this is important in determining how to handle this. You can read more about accessing rows from hidden pages here: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25168748/jquery-datatables-retrieving-information-from-other-pages)

Comment: @RyanWilson i create the datatable from a ajaxcall

Comment: @relo80 Then you'd probably be able to use the `data()` api and search the table for the proper row and add the class, but since it's hidden from view, I'm not sure what you hope to accomplish as they won't be able to see it anyway. Or use a combination of the `data()` api and the `page()` api to find the proper row, select the page it's on and then set the row's `className` - read more here (https://datatables.net/reference/api/)

Comment: @relo80 You can make use of `createdRow` function of `datatable`. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43402641). Since data is coming from ajax, you must have something in place to assign `id` on `tr`. You can use similar logic to add class in `createdRow`

Comment: @RyanWilson i need to add the class to the right row and "jump" to the resultpage where the row is in. How can i do it?

Comment: @relo80 I gave you what you need in my previous comment. You can use the `data()` api to find the row you are looking for and the `page()` api to set the page of the table, then add the `className` to the appropriate row. The documentation on datatables is pretty self explanatory on how to accomplish these tasks.

Comment: @pirate Adding the class works for the first page very well, but if the row with the selection class not on the first result page, it wont work.

Comment: @RyanWilson ok, thank you, i will have a look at this.

Comment: @relo80 This post may help you more as it shows how to get the page number of a specific row: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16826580/jquery-datatables-get-page-of-a-given-row)